# Laravel chmod(/var/dev/project/storage/oauth-public.key): Operation failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth, permissions, laravel-passport

After I updated the following packages I got an error that the **oauth-public.key** file couldn't be found.

> Package operations: 1 install, 2 updates, 0 removals
>
> Updating laravel/framework (v5.4.27 => v5.4.28): Downloading (100%)
>     Installing defuse/php-encryption (v2.1.0): Downloading (100%)
>     Updating league/oauth2-server (5.1.3 => 5.1.4): Downloading (100%)

Firstly I deleted the two **oauth-** files in project/storage and then executed this command: **php artisan passport:install** to generate new **oauth-** files.

Now I get the following error when trying to access an **api** route.

> (1/1) ErrorException
>   chmod(/var/dev/project/storage/oauth-public.key): Operation failed: Operation not permitted

**Stack trace**

> in CryptKey.php (line 51)
>
> at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'chmod(/var/dev/project/storage/oauth-public.key): Operation failed: Operation not permitted', '/var/dev/project/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php', 51, array('keyPath' => 'file:///var/dev/project/storage/oauth-public.key', 'passPhrase' => null, 'keyPathPerms' => '644'))
>
> at chmod('file:///var/dev/project/storage/oauth-public.key', 384)
>   in CryptKey.php (line 51)
>
> at CryptKey->__construct('file:///var/dev/project/storage/oauth-public.key')
>   in ResourceServer.php (line 50)

**File permissions**

```
-rw-r--r-- user:user oauth-private.key
-rw-r--r-- user:user oauth-public.key
```

**Update 1**

I found out that oauth Libaray introduced a security fix. [Oauth V5 Security Improvements](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/v5-security-improvements/)

> Version 5.1.4 is a backwards compatbile with other 5.1.x releases.
>
> You will notice in your server logs a message like this:
>
> You must set the encryption key going forward to improve the security of this library - see this page for more information https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/v5-security-improvements/
>
> To supress this notice once you have instantiated an instance of \League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer you should call the setEncryptionKey() method passing in at least 32 bytes of random data.
>
> You can generate this using base64_encode(random_bytes(32)). Alternatively if you’re using a framework such as Laravel which has a encryption key already generated you can pass in that (in the case of Laravel use env('APP_KEY')).

Problem is that the maintainer of Laravel Passport has to fix this.

**Update 2**

After I removed the vendor folder and executed **composer install** again I get still the same error.

Comment: me too. I got this error as well

Answer (score 27):

Try:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data storage/oauth-*.key
sudo chmod 600 storage/oauth-*.key
```

It solves my problem.

Comment: it solved the problem, but all other owner and groups are set to my user. So I think its not correct to set the owner to www-data?

Comment: Works great on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This solves the issue because "league/oauth2server" has breaking changes. See `/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php`. It's forcing both owner and permissions to be set in a specific way, `server:server` and `0600`. Also see: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/418

Comment: Thanks mate, in my case I had to make it chmod 660

Answer (score 12):

According to the latest `oauth-server 5.1.4` [update](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/v5-security-improvements/), you should set an encryption key which is not implemented yet in `passport 2.x`.

An easy and fast fix to this is by using `passport 3.x` which uses `oauth-server 6.x` by updating your `composer.json` file with:

```
"laravel/passport": "^3.0"
```

Then

```
composer update
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solution worked for me without changing any owner or permissions.

Answer (score 5):

Finally! I found the solution. ( CentOs )

```
chown apache:apache oauth-public.key
chown apache:apache oauth-private.key
```

At first you need to find the username of your server:
This will return the username you need

```
ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1
```

For me it's **apache**

Answer (score 5):

It would not be safe to change the owner of oauth-private.key to www-data:www-data. Only the oauth-public.key should be owned by www-data:www-data.

This should be sufficient:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data oauth-public.key
sudo chmod 600 oauth-public.key
```

Once done, check your permissions by running this in the storage folder:

```
ls -la
```

Owner of oauth-private.key should NOT be www-data:www-data.
Owner of oauth-public.key should be www-data:www-data

Answer (score 1):

composer install works fo me :)

Comment: tried it just now... but I get still the same error as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, i've temporarily rolled back to an earlier version of my composer.lock file. It looks like the OAuth package is trying to modify the permissions of the keys within the storage folder and my server is not having it.

Im going to take a look at the packages change log and see whats changed and perhaps rerun the updates after hours.

Comment: Yes, it's actually trying to change permissions. See this commit: https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/commit/2f8de3d2302beb490abb9475cf426148801c25c4

Comment: @mayid, spot on there. My server is not allowing that modification of permissions however, so we'll have to tweak it manually and ill post a comment with my outcome.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Laravel and Passport Version too.
if using latest Laravel 5.4 it uses Passport 3.0 which has the patch for Oauth package.

If you are using larvel 5.3 it uses Passport 1.0 ( you should upgrade !!) [no patch ] but this uses the stable version of league/OAuth-server which is at the time ( 5.1.4 ) which has the check [file](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/blob/5.1.4/src/AuthorizationServer.php#L142).

The solution for this:  you need to force install 5.1.3 version (Not ideal) but would fix the issue.
run in the project root.
`composer require league/oauth2-server 5.1.3`